# Может ли структура данных структурироваться структурой данных?

Tags: javascript, массивы, структуры-данных, очередь, стек

Я немного запутался. В [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2_(%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)#:%7E:text=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%20(%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%2C%20%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%2C%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)%C2%A0%E2%80%94%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%2C%20%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20(%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0)%2C%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%83%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%2C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B5%20(%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%20%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%BC)%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0.) пишется, что массив является структурой данных:

> Массив — структура данных, хранящая набор значений (элементов массива), идентифицируемых по индексу или набору индексов, принимающих целые (или приводимые к целым) значения из некоторого заданного непрерывного диапазона.

[Стек](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%20(%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB.%20stack%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0)%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%2C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%20%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%2C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B8%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0.) и [очередь](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C#:%7E:text=%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C%20(%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB.%20queue,first-out%20%E2%80%94%20FIFO).) также являются структурами данных. На [learn.js](https://learn.javascript.ru/array#metody-pop-push-shift-unshift) пишется, что массив может работать с такими структурами данных как стек и очередь.

Вопрос: получается, что структура данных может также структурироваться структурой данных? Либо же, насколько я понимаю, массив - это немного другая структура данных, в отличие от стека и очереди. Массив структурирует данные по индексу, а стек и очередь структурируют данные по тому, какой из них первый выходит/заходит (FIFO/LIFO). И получается что разные структуры данных по "типу" могут структурироваться другими структурами данных другого "типа"? ...Либо я что-то не так понял...

Comment: думаю все проще: стек и очередь можно реализовать через массив

Comment: там так и пишут __Существует и другой вариант применения для массивов – структура данных, называемая стек.__

Comment: Структуры данных зачастую реализуются на основе других структур данных, используя их в качестве строительных блоков. Например, упомянутый вами стек можно реализовать не только на основе массива, но и на основе  односвязного списка. Структура данных, реализованная поверх другой структуры данных — обычное дело.